# privileges oracle jdbc getMetaData

Tags: java, oracle

I'm using the JDBC Driver to connect to different database type.
My database's users have only view permissions on the Catalog.
It works fine for hive/teradata but not with Oracle.

With Oracle, I'm able to retrieve Schemas but not Tables/Columns.

Oracle privileges :

> SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE,  CREATE SESSION,  CONNECT

Java Code :

> DatabaseMetaData databaseMetadata = con.getMetaData();
>                                                                                 resTables = databaseMetadata.getTables("Test_Schema", null, null,
>   null);

But once I give select permission on tables, it works.

Do I miss something ?

Comment: what version are you using of JDBC driver?  It just queries all_objects o, all_tab_comments so select catalog should work in 18.3 at least.

Comment: Hi Kris, all_objets does not contain other users tables

Comment: The all in all_objets is for *all*  users respecting what's granted. 
 user_objects is the current schema only.

Comment: Thanks Kris, is it possible to grant access to metadata without granting access to data ?

Comment: Yes. Perform the sql

Comment: Yes ; query the dba_tables view directly since you have select_catalog role

Comment: I meant, is it possible to grant access to metadata without granting access to data and retrieve metadatas through the JDBC driver ? Without any queries because I'm using the JDBC's methods (getMetadata, getSchemas, getTables...). As it is a generic program for different database types

Comment: Not with the driver using all_ views.

Answer (score 1):

Using DatabaseMetaData.getMetaData replies on the underlying views all_objects , all_tab_comments, and all_synonyms. These views take into consideration what is granted for access.

SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE grants access to the catalog which would allow to query dba_objects.

To do what is asked, a mirrored Java API to DatabaseMetaData.getMetaData().getTables(..) can be easily written to use dba_xyz views. Something along the lines of this.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData;

public class MyMetaData extends OracleDatabaseMetaData {



    public MyMetaData(Connection conn) {
        super((OracleConnection) conn);
    }

    public synchronized ResultSet getTables(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String[] types) throws SQLException {
        // catalog isn't used
        // dba view based sql  

        String sql = "SELECT NULL AS table_cat,"+
        "       o.owner AS table_schem,\n       "+
        "       o.object_name AS table_name,\n  "+
        "       o.object_type AS table_type,\n"+
        "       c.comments AS remarks\n" +
        "  FROM dba_objects o, dba_tab_comments c\n"+
        "  WHERE o.owner LIKE :1 ESCAPE '/'\n    "+
        "  AND o.object_name LIKE :2 ESCAPE '/'\n"+
        "  AND o.owner = c.owner (+)\n    "+
        "  AND o.object_name = c.table_name (+)\n";

        // bind params

         PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
         stmt.setString(1, schemaPattern == null ? "%" : schemaPattern);
         stmt.setString(2, tableNamePattern == null ? "%" : tableNamePattern);

        return stmt.executeQuery();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        String conString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "klrice");
        props.setProperty("password", "klrice");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, props);
        // use this class
        MyMetaData md = new MyMetaData(conn);

        // test it out
        ResultSet rset = md.getTables(null, "ORDS_METADATA", null, null);
            while (rset.next()) {
                System.out.println(rset.getString(2));
            }    

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE`  allow SELECT privileges on data dictionary views(for exapmle `select * from dba_users`) 
, but  not for user tables.
You must explicitly specify the rights to the desired table for example 
`grant select,update,delete on need_table for user_name;
 grant select,update,delete on DEPARTMENTS to test;`

or give select right to all tables (bad practic).

```
[oracle10@aktp ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Wed Nov 21 14:39:55 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> grant select any table to test;

Grant succeeded.
```

.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thanks. Does it mean that it is not possible to give access to dba_users metadata whithout giving access to their data ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with jdbc. My solution is that simple.

```
create or replace synonym youruser.all_objects for dba_objects;
create or replace synonym youruser.all_tables for dba_tables;
create or replace synonym youruser.all_tab_columns for dba_tab_columns;
create or replace synonym youruser.all_users for dba_users;
create or replace synonym youruser.all_constraints for dba_constraints;
create or replace synonym youruser.all_cons_columns for dba_cons_columns;
```

That works well to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Lotar Schin, your solution is so simple and really works. After read the source code of the Oracle JDBC driver, I had a more complete list of synonyms:

```
create user metadata_collector identified by "password";
grant connect to metadata_collector;
grant select any dictionary to metadata_collector;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_objects for dba_objects;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_tables for dba_tables;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_tab_comments for dba_tab_comments;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_tab_columns for dba_tab_columns;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_col_comments for dba_col_comments;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_users for dba_users;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_constraints for dba_constraints;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_cons_columns for dba_cons_columns;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_arguments for dba_arguments;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_synonyms for dba_synonyms;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_col_privs for dba_col_privs;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_tab_privs for dba_tab_privs;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_ind_columns for dba_ind_columns;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_trigger_cols for dba_trigger_cols;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_indexes for dba_indexes;
create or replace synonym metadata_collector.all_types for dba_types;
```